# UpdateModel change MVC1 vs MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm converting an app from ASP.NET MVC 1 to MVC 3, but I ran into some problems when calling `UpdateModel()` when submitting a form.

Here is my model class:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int? SubValue { get; set; }
    public int AgeSub
    {
        get
        {
            return SubValue.Value - Age;
        }
    }
}
```

And in my controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult TestModelSave()
{
    TestModel tm = new TestModel();

    try
    {
        UpdateModel(tm);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("TestModelEdit");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    return View("TestModelEdit", tm);
}
```

If I leave SubValue null when I submit, in MVC 1 it works fine. But in MVC 3, when I call `UpdateModel(tm)` it throws an exception on the line `return SubValue.Value - Age;` in the TestModel class.

I could go and change `SubValue.Value` to `SubValue.GetValueOrDefault()`, but I don't want to have to do that. Why was this change made between versions of MVC?

Comment: Oh, right. It throws "Nullable object must have a value." when SubValue is null.

Answer (score 0):

If your code worked under MVC1 (and I can't understand how it would), then that would be just pure luck.  It *SHOULD* throw an exception if you try to access the value of a nullable int like that.

Your code is broken, and you should fix it.  Don't complain that it used to work, because if it did, it shouldn't have.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you could try. Your AgeSub property should have a null check on the subvalue property:

```
  public int AgeSub
    {
        get
        { 
            if(SubValue == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            return SubValue.Value - Age;
        }
    }
```

You can clean up your controller action and get rid of the try catch block as follows:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult TestModelSave()
    {
        TestModel tm = new TestModel();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if(TryUpdateModel(tm))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("TestModelEdit");    
            }

        }

        return View("TestModelEdit", tm);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The object cannot be null if you are to access a property of that object. So the best thing to do is to check if the object is not null and then try to access the property.
I highly doubt the same code works without any exceptions in MVC1 (if it is working what is the value you are getting in MVC1)

In your case you can do this for `AgeSub` to avoid an exception being thrown.

```
public int AgeSub
{
   get
   {
       return SubValue.HasValue ? SubValue.Value - Age : 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its a pretty old questions, however just for future reference,

In MVC 1,
UpdateModel method updates only the fields specified in the form collection
ModelState.IsValid checks the validity only only those fields that are modified.

In MVC 2 RC and above,
It is changed, now, Model.IsValid checks the validity of all the properties in the model, instead of just checking the modified field.

***This means, your AgeSub property was not validated when you called ModelState.IsValid in MVC1, but is called in MVC 2 and above***

Reference:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/05/asp-net-mvc-2-release-candidate-2-now-available.aspx#7335401

Also check the MVC 2 release notes.